# jquery's .css() and gradients

Tags: jquery, gradient

I have looked at several questions but I can't seem to make the .css() work with the variables and gradient I want. You should be able to drop two colors into the inputs and BANG it gives you a gradient but no dice. Any suggestions?

Below is my JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var colorTop = $("#color1").keyup(function () {
    var color1 = $("#color1").val();
    $("#demo").css("background", color1);
});

var colorBottom = $("#color2").keyup(function () {
    var color2 = $("#color2").val();
    $("#demo").css("background", color2);
});

function changeGradient(colorTop, colorBottom) {
    $("#demo").css({
        background: 'linear-gradient(' + colorTop + ', ' + colorBottom + ')'
    });
};
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xyhjppph/3/

Comment: and i forgot to add the jsfiddle: Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xyhjppph/3/

Comment: A jsfiddle link is nice, but also show your code in your question.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles You got it. I added the JQ I'm using for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling `changeGradient` anywhere. I suggest adding a button that will take the output of both inputs when clicked to change the background.

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/jyh18cnk/1/

Or, if you don't want the button, you could make the variables for colors global

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/ao0escev/1/

Comment: That does work but I was hoping to have it simply work when the values of both inputs are entered. I'm suddenly realizing that might take a lot more code than I initially thought.

Comment: Check the second fiddle. The background is updated when the values are entered, without a button

Comment: You are a winner. Thanks!